# How for each field do the validation from the server to the vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I think you need to transfer an array of errors and distribute them between forms. How will each field match the error?

```
this.$axios.post('signin', {
  user: {
    email: this.email,
    password: this.password,
  }
}).then(res => {


  if (res.data.success === false) {
    this.err_sn = res.data.message;
    console.log(res.data.message)

  }
```

Comment: Why you don't use `data()`: `passwordError` and `emailError` ?

Comment: Or use `Object` for error and each key is name of field. example:
`fiedlError: { email: null, password: null }` and use `this.fieldError = res.data`

Comment: I do not know how to bind the keys to each field for output errors

Answer (score 2):

You can catch the error using .catch

```
 .then(response => {
    // replaced function with =>
    console.log(response.data);
    this.items = response.data; // `this.items =` inst. of `items =`
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
    });
```

#### Update from link posted

This a snippet from the server validation section of link that you posted. As you can see they are displaying the errors returned from the server at the top of the form use `<p v-if="errors.length">`.

```
<form
  id="app"
  @submit="checkForm"
  method="post"
>

  <p v-if="errors.length">
    <b>Please correct the following error(s):</b>
    <ul>
      <li v-for="error in errors">{{ error }}</li>
    </ul>
  </p>

  <p>
    <label for="name">New Product Name: </label>
    <input
      id="name"
      v-model="name"
      type="text"
      name="name"
    >
  </p>

  <p>
    <input
      type="submit"
      value="Submit"
    >
  </p>

</form>
```

Comment: <input name="example"> <input name="example2"> <input name="example2">
to each field you need to output your error

Comment: it will catch any error associated with your post call. Are you trying to pick out individual error messages instead of just looking at the error as a whole?

Comment: I need individual error messages instead of just looking at the error

Comment: I do not know how to bind the keys to each field for output errors

Comment: I know that the errors are passed through the array. but how to distribute these errors between fields I do not know

Comment: you could write conditionals to pull the errors out of the errors object and then store them in variables. Then in the template you would use conditional span tags to display the errors in the the variable. I would recommend saving yourself the time and hassle and use something like https://github.com/monterail/vuelidate or https://github.com/baianat/vee-validate. I use vee-validate and it works well but either should do

Comment: I use vue validate as validation on the client. and I need to display an error from the server

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/form-validation.html#Server-side-Validation . as shown here

Comment: field validation is generally handled on the client which sounds like what your currently doing. Server errors are generally shown at the top of the form, if you look at the section on server side validation in the link that posted they also handle it at the top of your form. If you are already doing field validation there shouldn't be the need to do it a second time

Comment: then it is just a mistake to deduce

Comment: What do you believe the mistake to be?